# How to encode the page in utf8

Tags: php, mysql

After my connection query:

```
    $this->db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_psw, $db_name)or die ("error connection to sql");
```

i need to set the `utf8 encode`, so the old manner to do that is :

```
    $this->db->set_charset("utf8");
```

But this doesn't work since i use the OO `mysqli`. What's please the equivalent of that on `mysqli`?

Comment: How do you know its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
$this->db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_psw, $db_name)or die ("error connection to sql");
if (!mysqli_set_charset($this->db, "utf8")) 
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($this->db));
}
else
{
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($this->db));
}
```

And tell us what you get.

Comment: Hi, i got the second printf: `Current character set: utf8`

Comment: Ok, also, my Table and columns in the data base are encoded in `UTF8_general_ci`, however, when i try to fetch an accent word like `Sérgio` i couldn't find it :(

Comment: It also depends on the encoding of your source. If your text isn't encoded as UTF-8 and you try to insert it in a table which is waiting for UTF-8 text, you'll have problems like this. Try to fetch "S%rgio" and see what do you have in your DB.